# How do I get Vim to highlight matching parenthesis?

Tags: vim

When I browse code in Vim, I need to see opening and closing parenthesis/
brackets, and pressing <kbd>%</kbd> seems unproductive.

I tried `:set showmatch`, but it makes the cursor jump back and forth
when you type in a bracket. But what to do if I am browsing already written code?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
DoMatchParen
```

in your `.vimrc` file

or

```
:DoMatchParen
```

within vim itself.

Edit: This comes from the [pi_paren](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pi_paren.html) plugin (which is a standard plugin).

Comment: but that doesn't seem to work with vim version 6.3 that I use at work
Can you provide any suggestion for achieving the same functionality in vim 6.3

Comment: Sorry, no.  Your best bet would be to upgrade to a version of vim that's less than 5 years old.  I'm pretty sure you could run it from a USB key if you wanted to.

Comment: Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15) doesn't have this editor command either

Comment: In Vim 7.4 you can type in the command `:let loaded_matchparen = 1` and it should work

Comment: Make sure to set you highlight color to something useful with for example: `:highlight MatchParen ctermbg=blue guibg=lightblue`

Comment: That command actually stops DoMatchParen from loading @DavisDude

Answer (score 41):

`set showmatch` is your best bet.  you can also use the <kbd>%</kbd> command to jump between matching parenthesis, braces, brackets, quotes, etc.

Comment: I mentioned in the question that pressing % every time is a pain

Answer (score 1):

An upgrade of vim from version 6.3 to 8.0 might swap/upgrade the code file that manages this MatchParen functionality under `/usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/matchparen.vim`

The function to begin investigating a vim failure for highlighting matching brackets is called: `Highlight_Matching_Pair()`.  Do an echo and a sleep and step through the code until `matchaddpos(...)` runs.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you want is this plugin:

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=350

Comment: Kinda nice, but the point isn't to find unmatched ones per se, it's to see where the (usually properly matched and formatted) matching brackets are without having to be right on it (or typing %)