# vim parenthesis matching only while typing

Tags: vim, macvim

In emacs, as you type, it will show you the matching parentheses, but there is a separate setting to highlight matching parentheses that the cursor is on. Is there something I can write in .vimrc to make this happen? Everything I've found completely turns off parenthesis matching, which is not quite what I want.

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: Addressing the comment about a possible duplicate, that answer explains how to turn on what I want to turn off. I want paren matching as I type, but I don't want highlighting when my cursor is on a parenthesis. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get Vim to highlight matching parenthesis?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232274/how-do-i-get-vim-to-highlight-matching-parenthesis)

Answer (score 1):

```
" Briefly jump to the matching bracket when typing
set showmatch
" Turn off the default matchparen plugin (on demand):
NoMatchParen
" Alternatively (in your .vimrc, to completely disable the plugin):
let loaded_matchparen = 1
```